# Getting a PhD much later on

Tags: phd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Age and Graduate school](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/902/age-and-graduate-school)

Is it difficult to get a job as a professor if you don't go to a PhD program immediately after undergrad? For example, suppose you work for 5 years before returning to get a PhD? Is this very rare?