# Second attempt at PhD

Tags: phd

I couldn't complete the PhD at the end of third year because of unsatisfactory progress. That was three years ago. Now I am again thinking of applying for a PhD. The application requires an up to date CV. I am wondering how to mention about the previous PhD study and whether it is worthwhile at all to make such an attempt. I would be grateful for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Mention => I would say "yes", don't lie by omission. Anyone accepting to mentor you could be pretty upset finding out that you already tried a PhD program but "forgot" to mention it. Worthwhile => That depends of many factors, but mostly … of you. What makes you think that you could succeed where you failed previously? What changed? How a different institution / topic / place / supervisor would transform that attempt into a success?

Comment: Clément, thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. First of all I am 42 now. I am not sure whether it is a good idea to start PhD at this age. I am a professional for the last 18 years. During the PhD study, I wasn't very much sure whether to be engaged in the academic activities for long or go back to my main job and I wasn't also enjoying much. Now I want to retire from my job and concentrate fully in study heart and soul. Also I have a plan to select a research approach that fits more with my professional background.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you must include it in your CV. Concealing it could result in all sorts of trouble later.

Your cover letter or statement of purpose should explain what went wrong last time and what will be different this time around. For example, you could discuss the job vs. studies uncertainty you had last time, contrasted with your current intention to retire and study heart and soul.

For the age concern, see [How old is too old for a PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3426/10220). In particular, I did my PhD after retirement, in my 50's, and have no regrets.