# To enroll in to a PhD Program at the age of 65

Tags: phd, career-path, age

As a retired school teacher, and to become a professor at a university. Is it okay to get into a PhD program at the age of 65 and complete it to become a professor? Or is it too late and I can’t get employed at a university?

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: we have two above 60 PhD students here. Yes, possible. I doubt that they are planning to become professors though.

Comment: I wonder why you want to become a professor after 65? If you give your reasons, some may be able to provide more relevant answers. For example, if you have a big idea that you want to investigate and give to the world, then, big-ideas have not just come from professors. Gödel's outstanding contribution was (partly) before his PhD, for example.

Comment: Agreed with @ThomasKing - your goals here are very important.  Do you want the PhD in order to work on original research, do you want it so that you can teach in higher education, or all of the above *plus* a hope that you yourself will also be able to supervise new PhD students?  Would the field be in a field related to your existing expertise (subjects you teach already and know well) or would it be a break into a new field?

Comment: I think we need to know which country you are living in. I am aware of more than one country where Ph.D. students are employed by the government, hence subject to mandatory retirement restrictions.

Comment: I second the comment of @CarlChristian. For example in Germany you would already be too old to become a professor. There are laws that define that. "Just" getting your PhD on the other hand would be possible without problems if you find an adivsor.

Comment: I think this is three questions: 1. can I get my PhD  2. can I get into a PhD program and 3. can I continue to work as a professor.
I'm planning to do just 1. I'm doing the research on my own, then I'm sure I can find a professor and work with them for a year or so and get my PhD. Here in the Netherlands, 2 would be hard, 3. would be impossible unless you're Albert Einstein.

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/how-old-is-too-old-for-a-phd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How old is too old for a PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/how-old-is-too-old-for-a-phd)

Answer (score 51):

The realistic answer is: you can enroll in a PhD program at age 65. However, you are highly unlikely to get a tenure-track professorship after finishing a PhD program at that age. The big reason for this is that you're already above the retirement age, and many schools do have rules about how old you can be and still advise students. Moreover, you probably wouldn't represent a good "long-term investment."

On the other hand, you may be able to obtain a position as a part-time lecturer or adjunct faculty—in other words, for positions where you are not directly supervising PhD candidates.

Comment: At least in the US, it is generally illegal to discriminate based on age. Do you know how that works in a situation like this? I agree a tenure track position would be tricky though!

Comment: Most states are also right to work so employers can fire or not hire for any opinion they come up with after the fact as long as they don't say it to your face. I've actually had a cease and desist letter sent to an employer spewing garbage after the fact. Needless to say he forbade anyone from saying anything less risk a lawsuit but that may be as far as you can go.

Comment: @chessofnerd: I think the big issue would be is how competitive a 70-year-old's profile will be versus a younger person's, especially if the younger person has a postdoc under her belt, and the elder person only had a doctoral degree. It wouldn't be an "apples-to-apples" comparison, so age discrimination wouldn't be the deciding factor.

Comment: You can only prove age discrimination if they are stupid enough to tell you that is the reason. Just because the 28 year old got hired and not the 65 year old isn't proof of age discrimination.

Comment: @MaxW That's super true. I tend to agree a 65 year old is almost certainly going to have a hard time at this. I wish them luck though (if not for job prospect, for personal enrichment)!

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable replies....the reason of this typical question is as follows:

Comment: Well let me explain my career...I worked in Indian Army...for 24 yrs retired at 46...then  did my MS, MBA worked in corp ..became a guest professor at Univs in India...enrolled in PhD in India, completed recently. I had moved to USA in 2003 on GC........after coming here applied at Univs for a faculty job ..but they were not hiring... so I got certified to teach in schools...but I was never satisfied with school teaching. I could not get faculty job. Now I thought probably if I do 2nd PhD from US it may give me a chance to teach at higher level and also earn. Not looking for many yrs to work..

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable replies though...I do not mind relocating if anyone has any suggestions about applying to a particular University...

Comment: @Neil: Why not work as an adjunct lecturer?

Comment: @chessofnerd As I understand US employment law, you can discriminate if there is a factor of the job that would make that requirement important (for example, you could refuse to hire a male OBGYN if the clinic was for abused females who were afraid of men). If the University could come up with a suitable reason not to hire a 65-year old person (for example, the tenure-track would take to long) then they would likely be able to. It's why Hooters are allowed to hire only female waitstaff, as it's part the business identity.

Comment: I have a friend who started a PhD in late 50's and is planning to become a lecturer.

Comment: @chessofnerd In England and Wales it is illegal to discriminate on age, *except* you can refuse to hire people above retirement age.  Are you sure there isn't a similar exclusion in the US?

Comment: *" many schools do have rules about how old you can be and still advise students."* Can you please point to a few examples of established rules at some schools regarding this?

Comment: I don't have the links handy—however, faculty in several departments in the US told me that, and I know for sure in Germany that the only way to continue to advise students after 65 is with the blessing of the successor. (In other words, if the replacement faculty wants to take over everything, you're out of luck!)

Comment: @AdamDavis at my uni if you are above 60 you are not allowed to be the main advisor.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Having a mandatory retirement age is itself illegal in the US.

Answer (score 24):

It could be hard to get into a PhD program since potential advisers will be looking for students who will have many productive years ahead to establish a legacy.  But you don't need a PhD to be a lecturer at most universities here in the US.  You only need a master's.  It's not the same as the tenure track positions, which actually have professor titles, but the students still call you professor.

I'm 66.  I fell into teaching when my department chairman at University of Washington Bothell posted a request onto an IEEE email list for industry veterans to advise teams of seniors on their Capstone projects.  I thought I was volunteering to do it free and was surprised it paid and even more surprised they'd pay me.  With only a master's, it was never on my radar that any university would let me do this.  At Washington, I was an affiliate (part-time), but that led to being recruited to a full-time three year appointment at University of Michigan.  It's possible it could happen to you, too.

Comment: can you finish phd?

Comment: I studied in computer science.  We had two older instructors without PhDs who came in retired from the industry.  They were paid dirt but they were already living off retirement and passionate about helping the students.  As far as I know they were part-time.

Comment: @SSimon  I never started one and at this point, I think that ship has sailed.  When I first started teaching at UWB four years ago and realized a career in academia was something I really wanted, I applied to the PhD program on our Seattle campus but was not accepted.  It's possible they decided I simply wasn't that good or that while I was a good candidate for teaching, that I wasn't that promising for research.  (No one tells you why you weren't accepted.)  But I also suspect the limited number of productive years I could offer past the PhD was a factor.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton can you apply for grants and reaserch funding without phd?

Comment: @SSimon  Yes, it's possible but you won't be supervising PhD candidates and, realistically, you may not have time for research given your service obligations and the heavier teaching load you'll have as a lecturer.

Comment: @Pace  Yes, the big downsides to an affiliate appointment are that the pay is less than for a full-time appointment (even with the same teaching load) and you may not get benefits or an office or the right to vote on faculty business.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton In Germany, you would have much more rights, since now having experts teaching and supervising is a huge trend. I suggest you to try

Answer (score 2):

In most academic fields in the US it takes most people 10 years or more to go from the start of a Ph.D. program to starting a tenure-track academic position.  This includes the time to get a Ph.D. plus one or two postdoctoral or visiting assistant professorship positions.  If you start at 65 you're going to be looking for permanent positions when you're 75, and odds are that means you'd be looking at 10 years of preparation for a position you're likely to hold for less than five years.  You would also probably need to move to a new city at least twice during those ten years.  That doesn't seem like a great plan from your point of view.  Also it's not clear at this point whether you will still be interested in and able to do the job in your late 70s.  Lots of people at your current age are effective faculty, but the vast majority choose to retire before their late 70s.

Comment: How is what the "vast majority" of people do relevant? The OP specifically asked whether it would be possible to get an academic job after completing a PhD. Even if the OP only does hold a TT job for five years, maybe that would be five very happy and productive years, fifteen if you count the PhD and postdoc. And no one ever knows how much longer they have. Why is it still socially acceptable to devalue someone because of when they were born?

Comment: I’m just suggesting the OP think about the timing.  Maybe he will want to keep working in his late seventies, but the odds suggest that’s not the most likely scenario.  Might be true for him, I certainly have great colleagues in their late 70s.

Answer (score -4):

This may be difficult for younger academicians to comprehend: There is the adage that 'Those who can, do; those who can't, teach'. Let's say that I earn a B.S. or M.A. in computer engineering and go onto to start my own company, make a gazillion dollars, sell that company and start another. I sell that company and now have a net worth of twenty billion dollars. I'm sixty years old, I have the time and money. I've made my fortune, set up a foundation to do good works, and am now eager to explore other areas of life. I think, why not get that PhD? It has nothing to do with teaching; it's about challenge, accomplishment, and completion. And who knows, maybe some university will hire me--not because I'm young, but because I have wisdom and life experience.

Comment: And if you can't teach, teach the teachers, if that fails, become on inspector...