# Will my age affect my chances of finding a funded PhD position?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-process, age

I just finished my masters studies. My question is, **will my age (29) affect my chances of getting a funded PhD position?** I finished Bachelor of Engineering when I was 24 (took 6 years to graduate, normally my program was 5 years). I worked as a Lab course assistant (teaching the practical part of the course at a local university) for 2 years before I started my MSc a bit late due to financial reasons. I started working in industry a year ago (for same financial reasons) in a computer science field but irrelevant to the research area. I know that most of PhD *scholarship* positions *officially* require the applicant's age to be under 35, but do not they prefer someone who is 25 rather than 34?

I have two conference publications, one in IEEE, and about to send the third for journal publication. My field is computer engineering with a focus on the software side and I am trying to apply in Europe mainly.

Comment: "I know that most of PhD positions officially require the age under 35, but do not they prefer who is 25 that 34?"  Wow.  As Parrhesiastes's answer states, in the United States there are no official age requirements whatsoever; including them would (I presume; I am not an attorney) be legally actionable.  I am awfully surprised that European programs have this requirement: could you supply a citation?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Sorry, I did not clarify that is one of the requirement for most of the scholarships not generally applied

Comment: hawk: I'm sorry, I couldn't quite parse your answer.  I see you added "scholarship", but that does not lessen my surprise. (In my field, getting a PhD admission without a scholarship is almost meaningless.)  Anyway, could you provide a link to some page which describes this requirement?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Some examples (I just collected via google) [Germany (DAAD)](https://www.daad.de/deutschland/stipendium/musik-kunst/en/8594-international-scholarship-programme-akademie-schloss-solitude/),  [Japanese](http://www.studyjapan.go.jp/en/toj/toj0302e.html), [UK](http://www.beittrust.org.uk/Scholarships.htm), [China](http://prospectivestudents.leiden.edu/scholarships/scholarship/csc-scholarship.html)

Comment: For the sake of clarity, please adhere to the scope and context of your question. For instance, CSC scholarship is for Chinese nationals only. Similarly, Japanese scholarship enforces age only where the applicant has not completed "16 years of schooling."

Comment: And the German scholarship is not for PhD studies.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Europe is wildly different about age and family status in employment than the US.  In Germany there's a [maximum age](http://www.insidehighered.com/advice/2013/09/16/essay-german-expats-seeking-academic-jobs-their-home-country) at which you can be hired as a full professor!  They can and will pay you more for having a spouse and/or kids.  Furthermore, most European jobs ask for a photo along with the application!  It's all very shocking as an American, but I'm sure there are things that we do that would be shocking to a European.

Comment: @Noah: wow again.  That's three things that would absolutely never happen in the US.  (Why do they ask for a photo??)  One of my main reasons for participating in this site is to learn what academia is like outside of mathematics and outside of the US, so I am very glad to learn this.

Comment: Poking around a bit, it looks like it's rare for a photo to be required, but it's considered a standard part of a CV in at least several countries (Spain and Germany are the ones that come up).  I have no idea what could possibly justify it.

Comment: @Parrhesiastes Links I included are just indicative. I agree with you that it is not an official condition. But don't you think that Supervisors will prefer who's 26 years old rather than taking 34? There is always chance to get a funded PhD, but the age will negatively *affect* these chances. What do you think? (another link from Cambridge: http://www.jbs.cam.ac.uk/programmes/research-programmes/phd/fees-financing/financing-your-phd/)

Comment: @hawk Again, the links you are producing are related to funding bodies, grants and scholarships which are **not** prerequisite of PhD admission. Getting into PhD is one thing, getting funding is another. An applicant's age has nothing to do with general conditions of admission into a PhD program and specifically, it doesn't influence supervisors. From my personal experience, I have seen many PhD candidates who are more than 50 years old, so I don't see it's a problem.

Comment: @Parrhesiastes I here quote from Pete L. Clark above *"getting a PhD admission without a scholarship is almost meaningless"*. My question at the simple level is like that: *the supervisor is setting on his chair and there are two applications in front of him one for 26 years old applicant and the other 34 years old applicant. Even though the older has some industry experience, both have same academic qualifications. Which applicant will he choose*. I must emphasize that the chance of finding PhD is always there nonetheless. But is not narrower due to the age ?

Comment: @hawk As I said, general admission requirements are official, what is meaningful is personal. Your question leans toward getting personal opinions out rather than explanation of official requirements. The links that you're producing have nothing to do with a supervisor's selection since they are external to university. As far as a supervisor's selection criteria goes, I can say with some certainity that an A/A* journal publication is significant, age or gender has no value when it comes to research. To get more input, please update the original question as you stated in your last comment.

Comment: [Age and Graduate school](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/902/age-and-graduate-school) may help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is: no. Quite the contrary, many universities value the experience (preferably from industry) so it is beneficial. Also, your conference papers will be the most important factors in getting the PhD position and/or funding. I'd also emphasize that you should highlight the fact that you have a journal article (preferably A or A*) in progress.

I have not seen any such requirement which is restricting PhD or any academic degree to a specific age. In fact, doing so is illegal in most (read: all) European countries as it comes under age discrimination.

To narrow it down further, different funding bodies could impose their own restrictions per project, for instance DAAD's grant that you mentioned is "to promote and fund young artists" according to them, that is why it is restricted to a certain age group. A similar example could be feminist studies where it could be restricted to a single gender. Again, this has nothing to do with general conditions of admission.

Comment: I agree with you, but don't you think that professors (not officially) will prefer to choose younger researchers ?

Comment: @hawk As far as institutional requirements are concerned, what is official is not open for interpretation let alone personal opinion. As I said, it is illegal as per European laws and universities can be penalized severally if proven. For instance, the EU directive explicitly covers access to university education as stated [here](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/discrimination/files/present_a_discrimination_claim_handbook_en.pdf) on page 28. If you are still uncertain, refer to the EU Age and Employment regulations [here](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/discrimination/files/age_and_employment_en.pdf).

Comment: In light of the links provided in comments, which describe some scholarships that are definitely age restricted (in European countries), would you like to amend your statement?

Comment: The explanation already addresses the EU position i.e., DAAD. The rest of the links concern non-EU countries.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the idea of age restrictions is not to punish non-traditional educational paths, but to target "younger" professionals who are just getting started in their careers, rather than "returning" students. Thus, in some cases (including the DAAD link provided), you'll notice that there's a two-pronged requirement: either be under a certain age *or* have procured the degree within the last *X* years. This allows programs some flexibility while not excluding candidates who have made their way in a manner other than the traditional route.